# In CP/M, how does control-Z (hex 1a decimal 26) not interfere with ordinary file storage?

Tags: cp-m

Consider this - I have made a file called test.bin on a Windows machine.  It is exactly 256 bytes long, and contains nothing more than `00` to `ff` in each byte.

What would happen if I transferred this file to a CP/M system?  (in fact this is exactly what I am trying to do).

Since the CP/M end of file marker is control-Z or `1A` in hex, will CP/M think that my 256 byte file stops when it gets to byte `1A`?

I would have thought that hex `1A` can appear all over the place in binary files such as executable COM files.  How is it that CP/M uses this for an end of file marker without constantly truncating files early?

Is usage of control-Z at end of file a hard rule across CP/M - i.e. do all files have this as an end of file marker?

Is control-Z actually enforced by the operating system in any way, or is it simply a convention?

Comment: To highlight what @Raffzahn said, the ^Z part is part and parcel to TEXT files. Binary files had to deal with the file size issue differently, since you can't rely on ^Z not being in the data. <!----->

Comment: I'm pretty sure ^z only counted as a special character to the file system if a file name ends in ".txt". Otherwise files are considered binary and the file system has no interest regarding their actual content.

Comment: CP/M is very, very simple.  Logic typically went in the transient programs.

Comment: Windows and MS-DOS is stopping too ... its just a matter of type of file access you can open file as text or as binary ... the text files access type interprets certain control codes (or escape codes) as commands and many text and file related routines adherse them ... for example that is why if you print/list binary file as text you hear sometimes the beeps, sometimes its cut down premature etc ...

Comment: @RichF CP/M, with the exception of executables, did not "understand" filename extensions - i.e., nothing magic about .txt (or .dat or .dbf etc.). ^Z was treated special in any program that used a file as "text" rather than "binary". But the file extension had nothing to do with it, except to assist lowly humans in identifying files.

Comment: @manassehkatz Thank you for the correction of my misconception.

Comment: @RichF It is actually a common misconception because Windows tries to make it all work automagically. Which is great if a .txt file really is plain text and a .csv file contains comma-separated-values and a .doc file contains a Word document. But it leads to crazy errors when Windows starts an application based on the file extension and the file contents are actually something different. Alternatively, Windows doesn't have any idea what to do if (as happened to me just now) an emailed file doesn't include an extension - I know how to handle that, but regular users have no idea what to do.

Comment: I seem to recall in DOS that if you attempted to copy a file and it terminated early because of an ASCII 26 (EOF) you could over-ride the copy (or xcopy) command to tell it to use the file size instead by passing the command line parameter /b (binary)

Answer (score 21):

> What would happen if I transferred this file to a CP/M system?

Depends on your transfer utility and how it handles the data presented.

> Since the CP/M end of file marker is control Z or 1A in hex, will CP/M think that my 256 byte file stops when it gets to byte 1A?

No, at least not the OS itself. CP/M does not handle CTRL-Z (or any content) specially. Your file transfer utility may do so.

> Is controlZ actually enforced by the operating system in any way, or is it simply a convention?

No, it doesn't enforce anything. So it is a convention among text-based utilities.

> How do I know when I have got to the end of the end of an executable file?

(from a comment)

You don't. At least not at byte level. Loading an executable is always done up to the next 128 byte record.

---

**The long read**

CP/M, up to and including 2.2 did not maintain a bytewise file length in its metadata (directory extent). Length was only noted as the number of 128 byte records of the last extent. At DOS level read and write operation were always record based i.e. in 128 byte chunks (*1). While there was a function to calculate file size, it only worked with 128 byte granularity.

To allow termination of a file holding ASCII data, CTRL-Z was used as an end marker within the last record. All text oriented utilities followed that scheme. But there is no hard provision.

CP/M 3.0 utilized a previously unused directory extent byte to note the bytes used within the last record. For compatibility a value of 128 is noted as zero.

---

*1 - Random access could operate at byte level, but the 128-byte record granularity was still to be observed.

Comment: Interesting.  Looks like I am using CP/M 2.2 - does 2.2 actually save the exact file length somehow, even for binary files? How do I know when I have got to the end of the end of an executable file?

Comment: Sorry, I had the 2.2 part wrong, it wasn't until 3.0 that an exact file length was introduced. I also added further information to the answer.

Comment: The same misconception is also false about MS/PC/DR-DOS.  http://jdebp.uk./FGA/dos-character-26-is-not-special.html

Comment: @JdeBP For MS-DOS it's more of a compatibility addition toward CP/M to make CTRL-Z work alike on the command line. After all, File length was now maintained on byte level.

Comment: PIP knows about Ctrl-Z being EOF (See option O) and MSDOS has binary options on the copy command (for copy a.txt+b.txt c.txt)